# how to put values generated from a local function inside a global variable

Tags: javascript, function

I have some valuescoming from pubnub, I can see the data in pubnub console, how ever my global variable here remains an empty array when I see it through chrome console. There is no error this is why I think my function might ne wrong.

```
var data = [];
  pubnub = PUBNUB({
        subscribe_key : 'key'
    });


function get_data(){
  data = pubnub.subscribe({
        channel : "channel",
        message : function(message){
        return message
    }
})
}

console.log(data)
```

Comment: ................huh???

Answer (score 0):

This will work, `data` will get scoped to the global if it doesn't exist inside the function. JavaScript does lexical scoping in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window` (browser) or `global` (browser/node) to assign global variables.

```
global["data"]=value;
```

Special care must be taken if windows, workers, subprocesses etc are used to share data inbetween.